# Activity collides with AsyncTask? How to implement AsyncTask into GUI?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am sorry for my bad english skills. I'm new to programming/stackoverflow and try to create a little android quiz app. This app has to connect to a php server and login/getquestion...

The simplest example is the login. The user has to type in his data and then i have to connect.
To provide that the Gui doesnt freeze i have to use asynchronous tasks.

Here the activity's code:

```
 public void login(final String username, final String password) {
     final Activity a = this;
     FutureTask t = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
         public Object call() {
             Connection.GetInstance(a).login(username,password);
             afterLoginTry(username,password);
             return null;
         }
     });
     t.run();
 }
```

This calls a method in another class, which calls another `FutureTask` which calls an `AsyncTask`. At the end there is always an public synchronized method such as `afterlogintry()`. This works but it's a bit slow and i think dirty code.

My main problem is that i don't know how to give results back through different layers of classes and especially to the activity without using hotfixes all the time.

Is there any good explanation or tutorial, which describes how to design such a construct?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

The way you can pass `AsyncTask` results back to other classes, is by declaring callbacks for the task, that will then report the result to a listener. Here is how it works.

First, you must declare an interface in your `AsyncTask` which contains a method that will send out the result of the task. So in my example task below, my result is a String. The String gets passed to `onPostExecute()` when the task finishes its work. I then call my callback method on a registered listener, and pass that return value on to whoever is listening for it. You register a listener by passing in an instance of your callbacks from whichever class is creating the task.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    MyTaskCallback listener;

    public MyTask(MyTaskCallback listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String input = params[0];

        //do work
        input += "did some work on this String";

        return input;
    }

    //When the thread finishes its work, this gets
    //called on the main UI thread
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onResultReceived(result);
    }

    public interface MyTaskCallback {
        void onResultReceived(String result);
    }
}
```

So next we need to register a listener for these callbacks, so when the result comes in from the task, it will get reported directly to our class. So let's say we have a simple Activity. The way we register the callbacks is to use the `implements` keyword on our class declaration, and then to actually implement the callback method in the class itself. We then create our task, and we pass in `this` which is our Activity that implements the callbacks. A simple example Activity that does this looks like this:

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyTask.MyTaskCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        //we pass in "this" because our Activity itself
        //implements the callbacks below.
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(this);
        myTask.execute();
    }

    //Here we implement our callback method, so the task
    //can send its results straight through here
    public void onResultReceived(String theResult) {
        Log.d("TASK RESULT", "Here is our result String: "+theResult);
    }

}
```

Now, our task has our Activity connected to it, through the callbacks we passed into it. So now when our task gets a result, we can send it directly to our listener, which is our Activity, and the result will come right through to our implemented `onResultReceived` method.

Callbacks are a great way to pass information around between classes while also keeping everything very separated. Hope this helps!